# XCode automatically manage signing endless loop

Tags: ios, xcode

I use XCode 11.3 but when I check automatically manage signing in Signing and Capabilities, it is stuck in an endless loop:

1. Creating certificate

[image]

2. Creating provisioning profile

[image: creating_provisioning_profile]

3. Waiting to repair:

[image: waiting_to_repair]

Then it repeats from the beginning.
Because of this I cannot deploy even the most basic app on my device.
Do you have any solutions for the problem?

Comment: I faced the same problem in my XCode 11.4 on Catalina

Comment: Same for me on xCode 11.5 on Catalina

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem before. After upgrading my macOS to the latest version, the problem is gone. Currently my macOS version is 11.4 and Xcode version is 12.5.